# Java frame not displaying properly during a while loop

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, concurrency, jframe

Here's a serious issue im having with a jFrame. I have one "Main Frame" where everything is done from, however i have another frame with a gif image in it (Loading, that circle that goes round and round), that is used as a splash screen saying "Processing, Please wait", however when i pull through that frame and my while loop runs, the frame goes blank and nothing displays until after the loop.

I am assuming that this is due to the while loop consuming computer resources and "blocking" any other process from running.

Please advise on what i should do.

the code for declaring the new frame is standard but i will post it anyway below.

```
Processing nc = new Processing();
nc.setVisible(true);
```

Here is my full code so you can see what im trying t achieve:

Code from frame 1 (Excel Extractor):

```
Processing nc = new Processing();
    nc.setVisible(true);

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    int option = chooser.showOpenDialog(this); // parentComponent must a component like JFrame, JDialog...
    if (option == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    File selectedFile = chooser.getSelectedFile();
     directory = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
     System.out.println(directory);

    }


   //create a input stream for your excel file from which data will be read. 
   DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd");
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmmss");
   String curdate = dateFormat.format(new Date());
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.getTime();
   String curtime = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
try{

FileInputStream excelSheetInput = new FileInputStream(path);
//POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(excelSheetInput);
    XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelSheetInput);
    //get first work sheet in your excel file.
    Sheet sheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
    //we will read data in first rows(0) second column(1)
    Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
    Row myRow1 = sheet.getRow(0);
    Cell myCell1 = myRow1.getCell(0);
    String header="";
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator1 = myRow1.cellIterator();
    int rowCount = 0;

    while(cellIterator1.hasNext()) {

                            Cell cell1 = cellIterator1.next();

                            switch(cell1.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    header = header + "\""+cell1.getBooleanCellValue()+"\"" + ",";
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    cell1.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
                                     header = header + "\""+cell1.getStringCellValue()+"\""+",";
                                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    header = header + "\""+cell1.getStringCellValue()+"\""+",";
                                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                            }
    }

    Row myRow = sheet.getRow(1);
    Cell myCell= myRow.getCell(0);
    Iterator<Cell> cellIterator;
    String firstCell = myCell.getStringCellValue();
    int count =1;
    String nextCell;
    String Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
    String num = firstCell;
    System.out.println(Matter);
    fWriter = new FileWriter(new File(directory, num+"_"+curdate+"_"+curtime+".csv"));
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    writer.write(Matter);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.write(header);
    writer.newLine();
    String temp;
    while(rowIterator.hasNext())
    {


        //temp = "" + rowCount;
        //jLabel5.setText(temp);
        myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
        cellIterator = myRow.cellIterator();
        Cell myCell2 = myRow.getCell(0);
        nextCell= myCell2.getStringCellValue();


        if(nextCell.equals(firstCell))
        {

            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                            switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

                                     System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");

                                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    writer.write(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");
                                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                    writer.write(cell.getStringCellValue()+",");
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
            System.out.println();
            writer.newLine();
            count++;
            rowCount++;



        }
        else
        {          

            writer.close();
            myRow = sheet.getRow(count);
            myCell2= myRow.getCell(0);
            nextCell=myCell2.getStringCellValue();
            firstCell=nextCell;
            Matter = "Matter Number: "+firstCell;
            num = firstCell;
            System.out.println(Matter);
            fWriter = new FileWriter(new File(directory, num+"_"+curdate+"_"+curtime+".csv"));
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
            writer.write(Matter);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write(header);
            writer.newLine();
        }


    }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}

  try {
    nc.dispose();
    writer.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(FileChooser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
```

The second frames code (Processing):

```
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
    jLabel1.setText("Processing, Please Wait...");

    jLabel2.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabel2.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/loading.gif"))); // NOI18N

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel2)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    pack();
}
```

Comment: What thread is the while loop running on? If your while loop is running on the Event Dispatch Thread painting and event processing will be blocked until the while loop finishes.

Comment: Basically what im focusing on is the processing nc = new processing();

Comment: without code was better, for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, more to see in answer by @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the full extent of what you are trying to do, it's not entirely possible to you an exact answer.

From the sounds of things your trying to run long running tasks within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread. This thread is responsible for, amongst other things, processing repaint requests.

Blocking this thread, prevents Swing from repainting itself.

From what I can tell, you want to use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). This will allow you to performing your work in a background thread, while re syncing updates back to the EDT

**Updated with example**

I know you said didn't "want" to use a `SwingWorker`, but to be honest, it's just simpler and safer...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class LongRunningTask {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LongRunningTask();
    }

    public LongRunningTask() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                new BackgroundWorker().start();

            }
        });
    }

    public class BackgroundWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

        private JFrame frame;

        public BackgroundWorker() {
        }

        // Cause exeute is final :P
        public void start() {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spinner.gif"));
            JLabel label = new JLabel("This might take some time");
            label.setIcon(icon);

            frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            frame.add(label);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);

            execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

            System.out.println("Working hard...");
            Thread.sleep(1000 + (((int)Math.round(Math.random() * 5)) * 1000));
            System.out.println("Or hardly working...");

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            frame.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: MadProgrammer thank you for your replies, they are always very useful. However in this case im not sure im going to invoke a SwingWorker? the second frame runs after the user has selected an output path and outside the while loop, so surely this is one process?

Comment: The while loop is still going to block the UI. If you intend to interact with the UI from this loop, the SwingWorker is your best choice, otherwise you will need some kind of thread, but then y have the problem of call backs and resyncing them back to the UI later, which SwingWorker would resolve for you

Comment: i have no intention of interacting with the frame, its like a loading pane but is there simply to tell the user that the application is processing the request and nothing more.

Comment: The only thing you need to do is be able to to tell when the loop is complete. Take a look at SwingUtililites.invokeLater

Comment: the invokeLater method doesnt seem to work for me the gif image still doesnt display until the loop is done, however the text now shows

Comment: Added an example - I know, it's a `SwingWorker`, but it's simple and it works (and yes, my little gif spinner spins)

Answer (score -1):

You use Timer Class in java.util package and schedule timertask to close the splash screen after some time say 2 min or the task is completed.

```
 final Processing nc = new Processing();
 nc.setVisible(true);
 Timer timer = new Timer():
 TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
      public void run() { 
          nc.setVisible( false );
          // to do disposing nc
      }
 };
 timer.schedule( task, 1000 * 3 ); // dispose the processing frame after 3 minutes
```

Comment: No, you shouldn't. Using java.util.Timer does not execute the within the run method of the Event Dispatching Thread, which is a violation of the threading rules of Swing. You could use javax.swing.Timer instead though

Comment: I know from past experiences the java.util.time never works properly in fact it blocks the EDT if im correct? The one to use if using the time is a javax.swing.timer... i could be totally wrong but im pretty sure thats what ive read up, but in this case a timer wont help it needs to run as long as the while loop runs

Comment: java.util.Timer is executed within the context of the thread that the scheduler creates for it, this would most likely not be the EDT, as it has nothing to do with Swing or AWT. The Swing timer guarantees that the actionPerformed method is executed within EDT, so if you're going to interact with the UI from within the timer, then you need a Swing timer